# How do I declare a buildscript, dependencies and plugins in the settings.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, compilation, continuous-integration, liferay, continuous-deployment

**TD;LR:** I want to be able to build a project by applying some required dependencies and plugins, in order to be able to do a kind of lightweight CI/CD build in GitLab.

**Long explanation:** Liferay provides you with what they call a workspace, which adds certain dependencies by declaring a `workspace` plugin in the `settings.gradle` file. However, in order to create such workspace, a 400Mb SDK is required to be downloaded. I could create an image in Docker hub with the Blade CLI preinstalled —which isn't a bad idea at all—, but I'd like to know if it is possible to do it only using Gradle.

1. I can't include or touch the project's `build.gradle` file, in the sense of adding some `include`, because that would break the compilations from the IDEs.

---

When creating a new project, the project's `build.gradle` file contains the following contents:

```
dependencies {
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.asset.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.comment.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib.dynamic.section"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib.form.navigator"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib.util"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.layout.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.site.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api"
        compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api"
        compileOnly group: "jstl", name: "jstl"
        compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations"

        cssBuilder group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.css.builder", version: "3.0.2"
}
```

In order to be able to compile it outside Liferay's workspace, I need to add the following things:

```
buildscript {
        dependencies {
                classpath group: 'com.liferay', name: 'com.liferay.gradle.plugins', version: '11.0.74'
                classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins.target.platform", version: "2.1.9"
        }

        repositories {
                maven {
                        url "https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
                }
        }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: "com.liferay.plugin"
apply plugin: "com.liferay.target.platform"

dependencies {
        targetPlatformBoms group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.bom", version: "7.2.1"
        targetPlatformBoms group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.bom.compile.only", version: "7.2.1"
        targetPlatformBoms group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.bom.third.party", version: "7.2.1"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.asset.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.comment.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib.dynamic.section"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib.form.navigator"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.frontend.taglib.util"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.layout.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.site.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel"
        compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.taglib"
        compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api"
        compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api"
        compileOnly group: "jstl", name: "jstl"
        compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations"

        cssBuilder group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.css.builder", version: "3.0.2"
}
```

My idea is to have a "parent project" with the structure below, which gets cloned into the CI/CD pipeline, and moves the project to be compiled inside the "modules" directory:

```
.
├── modules
│   └── my-project-portlet
│       ├── bnd.bnd
│       ├── build
│       ├── build.gradle
│       └── src
└── settings.gradle
```

---

The question is: how do I include the `buildscript`, `apply plugin`s and the four `targetPlatformBoms` in the `settings.gradle` file?

I've read that maybe there's a way of doing it using the `buildSrc`, but it seems to be discouraged[1][2][3] in favour of composite builds. So I don't know where to head from here...

Thank you in advance

[1]: https://proandroiddev.com/stop-using-gradle-buildsrc-use-composite-builds-instead-3c38ac7a2ab3

[2]: https://medium.com/@wzieba/an-argument-against-buildsrc-defined-dependencies-or-how-to-seamlessly-keep-your-gradle-8e0bfd7ee8e3

[3]: https://androidsweets.ongoodbits.com/2020/05/29/stop-using-gradle-buildsrc

Comment: Have you concidered using gitlab cache to store the 400Mb SDK ?

Comment: I'll probably end up creating a Docker Image with the Blade Cli installed, but I wanted to know if there's a way of doing it just using Gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you can't modify your `build.gradle`, but you can modify your `settings.gradle` or you want to add a `settings.gradle` file to a project that does not have a `settings.gradle` file right now. In this case, you can simply configure your project(s) using the [`Gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html) instance provided by the [`Settings`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html) object that is used to evaluate the `settings.gradle` file:

```
gradle.rootProject {
    // modify your root project
}

gradle.allprojects {
    // modify all projects in your build
}
```

However, for your specific use case I would recommend using an [initialization script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) instead. Initialization scripts are only executed automatically when they are placed in the `.gradle` folder of your local user directory, so you might store them somewhere else (even directly with your project) and add them to your build using the `-I` command line option only when needed (e.g. when running on the CI server).

You can use the same code as in the example above for your initialization script, however you can omit the `gradle.` part from the statements because initialization scripts are evaluated directly against a `Gradle` instance.

Adding repositories or dependencies should be no problem from inside a `settings.gradle` file or from an initialization script, so you can start your initialization script like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
         targetPlatformBoms group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.bom", version: "7.2.1"
         targetPlatformBoms group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.bom.compile.only", version: "7.2.1"
         targetPlatformBoms group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.bom.third.party", version: "7.2.1"
         // ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is possible to call `buildscript` from a `settings.gradle` file or from a initialization script, because this block is a little bit special in the way it gets evaluated by Gradle. There is also an issue that you can't apply plugins from outside `build.gradle` using plugin identifiers. You must use the plugin type (the Java class that implements the plugin) instead:

```
apply plugin: "com.liferay.plugin"
// ->
apply plugin: package.path.to.LiferayPlugin
```

Comment: Thank you for setting me in the right path. You were right, I couldn't use `buildscript`, and because of that I was having trouble when trying to apply the plugins, even if I used the package + class names as you suggested. However, [thanks to another answer in the Gradle user forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/apply-plugin-configuration-in-init-gradle-script/32015/2), I have been able to compile everything without touching the `build.gradle` file. Thank you again! I am going to modify my question to include the final init script.

Comment: @MikelAlejoBR Instead of editing your question to include the solution you should add another answer with the final code, because it better suits the Q&A style of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lukas' answer, I have been able to finally get it working. As he pointed out, I couldn't use the `buildscript` code, as when trying to apply the plugins Gradle complained that they couldn't be found. So, I used `initscript` instead as pointed by [another answer in the Gradle user forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/apply-plugin-configuration-in-init-gradle-script/32015/2).

I found the group + class name by looking in the JARs of the following directories:

- `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.liferay/com.liferay.gradle.plugins.target.platform/2.1.9/`
- `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.liferay/com.liferay.gradle.plugins/11.0.74`

```
initscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.liferay', name: 'com.liferay.gradle.plugins', version: '11.0.74'
        classpath group: 'com.liferay', name: 'com.liferay.gradle.plugins.target.platform', version: '2.1.9'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: com.liferay.gradle.plugins.LiferayPlugin
    apply plugin: com.liferay.gradle.plugins.target.platform.TargetPlatformPlugin

    dependencies {
        targetPlatformBoms group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'release.portal.bom', version: '7.2.1'
        targetPlatformBoms group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'release.portal.bom.compile.only', version: '7.2.1'
        targetPlatformBoms group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'release.portal.bom.third.party', version: '7.2.1'
    }
}
```